# How to check if a warning is disabled or not?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Is there an option to check if a warning is disabled during a C++ cpp compilation process?

I'm looking for something like (pseudo-code)

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4500)

#if pragma warning 4500 is disabled
     // some code for 4500 disabled case
#else
     // some code for 4500 enabled case
#end if
```

Comment: Just enable all warnings - they are there for a reason. If you have to disable them then use pop and push directives for the pragma around the minimal code block

Comment: Anyway why are you repeating the code - guess it has the same functionality

Comment: @EdHeal - i am not... i got a compile warning if i exclude a header file from the build which doesn't exist when i include that file. i wanted to check if that header file is disabling that warning

Comment: Why the if statement?

Comment: @EdHeal - W'all isnt practical with vc++. W'4 is ok though.

Comment: @NirMH - I don't think what you are asking is possible - why not just search the offending header file for "4500".

Comment: @snowcrash09: it is not just 1 header file to look for... this header file is adding a complete library (third_party), so theoretically, i can search in all header files in the third_party, but i was seeking some programmatic support.